# XSL grouping and wrapping of tags

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

Need some help with one xsl transformation.
I got an XML with the following format

```
    <p class="list">
        <a href="../link-1.mp4">First Vid </a>
     </p>
     <p class="indent">test</p>
     <notes><p>TEST ME NOTE</p></notes>
     <p class="list">
        <a href="../link-2.mp4">Second Vid </a>
     </p>
```

This needs to be converted to something like

```
<ul>
        <li class="list">
           <p>
              <a href="../link-1.mp4">First Vid </a>
           </p>
           <p class="indent">test</p>
           <notes>
               <p>TEST ME NOTE</p>
           </notes>
        </li>
        <li class="list">
           <a href="../link-2.mp4">Second Vid </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
```

what i did is

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <li class="list">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </p>
    </li>
</xsl:template>
```

But that created li for all p elements and i lost the notes tag.
How can i wrap those nodes between the class list to the first li?

Comment: Have you read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info and tried one of the approaches there (`group-starting-with="p[@class = 'list']"` for instance)?

Answer (score 1):

You could use group-starting-with, for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <output>
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="input/*" group-starting-with="p[@class='list']">
                <li class="list">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </li>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </ul>
    </output>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/aiyneL

Comment: Worked really well. Thanks a lot

Comment: @JinoJohnDevasia You're welcome. If your question is answered please mark the answer as accepted.